# Optimizing page_manager_node_view

Tags: 6, proxies, caching

according to newrelic's dashboard /page_manager_node_view is:

- most time consuming (97.1%)
- slowest average response time (2050ms)
- apdex most dissatisfying (95.6%)
- highest throughput (14.4rpm)

I have apc and memcache enabled, yet to crawl about 8k pages and that's after some optimization (enabling cache on some of views) I was able to get down to 237min instead of 460min (before enabling cache on views).

we're using pressflow-6.28 on redhat6.4 w/ php5.3.3, there are two web heads residing behind varnish-3.0.4, web heads doesn't seem like experiencing heavy loads (0.2 15 min).

.. this is too much .. any suggestions?

Comment: "web heads doesn't seem like experiencing heavy loads" - so what do you want, really? What exactly bothers you? Crawling under 2 seconds per page seems pretty good to me.

Comment: I'd like to see if I can speed it up and/or optimize it to be able to serve of pages faster)